# VSCode-Can't find the folders in explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

[This image is of the extension something called git.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNDKK.jpg)
In VS Code i cant find the folders in the explorer. Tried many things. As shown in the image source control is the only thing i can find in there (git extension). I have the explorer but directories are not shown in there. There isn't an option to display the directories normally. Help me with this....

I checked everything in the settings, but did not find the option to display the directories normally.
[Trying to get the folders as shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pu9zW.png)

Comment: execute the command: **View: Reset View Locations**